# My terraform state remain empty on dns_config.cluster_dns_scope using google_container_cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

**Terraform**: v1.1.7
**Provider**: hasicorp/google v4.12.0

I try to spawn a GKE cluster with a specific dns configuration:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name                     = local.cluster_name
  location                 = local.region
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  network                  = module.gke_vpc.network_name
  subnetwork               = module.gke_vpc.subnetwork_name
  project                  = local.project
  dns_config {
    cluster_dns = "CLOUD_DNS"
    cluster_dns_scope = "VPC_SCOPE"
  }
}
```

TF is able to spawn it, but in its state, the `dns_config.cluster_dns_scope` remains empty, meaning that when I do a `terraform plan` I always get a change planed:

cluster_dns_scope : "" -> "VPC_SCOPE"

I tried the different values for `cluster_dns_scope`:

- DNS_SCOPE_UNSPECIFIED
- CLUSTER_SCOPE
- VPC_SCOPE

But I always get the same result.

I could modify my state as a workarround but the idea is to re-use the same TF module for several projects, so it's not what I want to do.

Any idea?

Comment: It seems like it's a Pre-GA feature? Maybe that's the reason why it's not working as expected?

Comment: I may have found the root cause [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-dns#dns_scopes), it can't be changed once the cluster has been spawn.
It may have been spawn without this parameter... I'm testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way to go about it but I saw mentioned in some docs that [dns_config](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-dns#dns_scopes) was GA; in a terraform issue someone thought this was being [promoted from beta](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/pull/5495). So, I added the `google-beta` provider to see if it was:

```
% cat provider.tf
# Check Releases here: version numbers tend to match, and should
# https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/releases
# https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google-beta/releases
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2.9"
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.3.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  region = var.region
  project = var.project_id
}

provider "google-beta" {
  region = var.region
  project = var.project_id
}
```

Then specified the provider in the GKE block:

```
% cat gke.tf
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  provider         = google-beta
  name             = var.cluster_apps
  location         = var.region
  enable_autopilot = true

  network    = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.name

  dns_config {
    cluster_dns        = "CLOUD_DNS"
    cluster_dns_scope  = "VPC_SCOPE"
    cluster_dns_domain = var.dns_name
  }
}
```

After that, it passed:

```
% tf validate
Success! The configuration is valid.
```

This is pretty late-breaking stuff so it might be in the latest version of Terraform:

```
% tf version 
Terraform v1.2.9
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.3.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v4.3.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.3.0. You can update by downloading from            <- could upgrade
```

At least Terraform is happy for now; let's see if GCP accepts it `:-P`

Comment: Also asked HashiCorp community support directly:  https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/when-does-the-dns-config-of-google-container-cluster-go-ga/44736